# Use getUserMedia on a website which should then communicate through a non-secure websocket connection

Tags: cordova, websocket, getusermedia

I have a use case where I need to capture the camera stream with getUserMedia() in a secure context of a website. The website should communicate with a websocket server within a mobile app (based on Cordova) on the local network.

The issue:

- The app uses an insecure websocket connection ws:// (not wss://), because there is no support for certificates for this kind of app.
- The website **must** use https, otherwise it won't be able to use getUserMedia() due to browser policies.
- One can't use insecure websocket (ws://) connections on secure websites due to browser policies.

Is there any way to solve this? Would it help to create a PWA from the website which can be added to the homescreen/desktop on the users device? I don't know if different security policies would apply in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a browser to break its rules about security for getUserMedia and websockets without doing unnatural acts to put it into debug mode.  Because cybercreeps.

But, if you need to push data TO a localhost http (not s) server, you can do it with a series of POST requests.  They'll be reasonably efficient locally.  Something like this might work (not debugged).

```js
function dataavailable (chunk) {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.set('media', chunk.data);
    fetch('http://localhost:8123/media/endpoint',
           {method: 'post', body:chunk.data })
}
```

If your local server can handle http1.1, it will use a persistent connection.